# Can you create interactive pdf with changing images on mouseover?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Is it possible to produce `pdf` files with InDesign that have interactive images on them?

For example, the initial appearance of the image is black/white but once the mouse touches it, it changes to a colour image.

Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried anything yet??

Comment: By embedding SWFs you can do that.

Comment: Yes, but...while Adobe has pushed for interaction in PDFs, it's still not the norm, so tends to be something very unfamiliar to users and, as such, may be completely lost on them.

Answer (score 3):

You must have the two images, then:

1. Place the first image
2. Right click on the image and go to <kbd>Interactive > convert to button</kbd>
3. Choose "Mouseover"
4. Enable "2nd layer mouseover"
5. Change to the second image (in the links panel)
6. Save as "Interactive PDF"

Done! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtKbisIoSkw) really helpful with interactivity in InDesign documents, hope it helps! Also remember to change the export option to 'Save as type: Adobe PDF (Interactive)' if you are exporting to a PDF.